# Chart c#: change color of radial lines

Tags: c#, charts, data-visualization, geometry

I have made doughnut chart with 100 elements, I have 2 pointers and I would like to highlight the elements indicated by my 2 pointers.

So, for 1 pointer I have highlited with Orange the Color property

```
this.chart1.Series[0].Points[i].Color = Color.Orange;
```

For the 2nd pointer I would like to highlight the radial lines

```
this.chart1.Series[0].Points[i].BorderColor = Color.Blue;
```

But unfortunately,setting the BorderColor does not modifies the BorderColor of both the radial lines
[image]

So it seems it isn't highlighted the radial line next to the current one

Here I have tried to highlight even the next element, but you see the result..

```
this.chart1.Series[0].Points[i+1].BorderColor = Color.Blue;
```

[image]

Do you know any workaround for this?? 
Thank you very much

Comment: Lokks like the only workaround, except for drawing the missing line yourself, is to turn off Borders for the whole series. Then it works fine but it will not look the way you want iit ito, obviously.

Comment: For examples on how to draw on a chart see my post on drawing to a [polar](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+polar) chart. It will have to be adapted a little for doughnut.. If you run into trouble do ask again..!